# Generate log4j timestamp format in linux date

Tags: linux, logging, rsyslog

I want to mimic the format used in log4j for timestamps using the linux date (just some quick scripting)

On log4j the format is defined as
`%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}`
That would translate into lines like:

> 2016-03-10 07:01:09,778
>   2016-03-10 07:01:09,784

Can this be accomplished in date? The closer I got was using

```
date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%N"
```

But this still has 9 digits instead of 3, any ideas? I'd prefer not using sed/cut,etc, but if there's no alternative it'd be fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Formatted Date From Timestamp With Rounded Milliseconds Bash Shell Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036763/get-formatted-date-from-timestamp-with-rounded-milliseconds-bash-shell-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `%N` is giving you the number of nanoseconds, (one billion per second) hence the nine digits, and GNU `date` doesn't have a milliseconds option.

Thankfully we can specify the field width like this

```
date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N"
```

To turn billionths into thousandths.

M.